# QGIS graphical modeler: how to automatically enter parameters in r.drain.coordinate tool

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, parameters

i am carrying out a cost least path analysis and i am using QGIS. The processing tools i am using are: r.cost.full and then r.drain.coordinate
Considering i have more than 1000 layer to process (starting and ending points) i have built a model. Everything works except r.drain.coordinate which requires to input E,N coordinates of the starting point (which is the ending point for what i am doing). I have tried to add the coordinate as attribute values from a table (see images below) but although the algorithm runs i do not get what i want.
Anybody has got a clue? A script that can do the job is welcome too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using the **Table** parameter for `N` and `E`?

Comment: @Joseph: i was using a vector file (point) and then two attribute fields (the parent was the vector file) which i had called N and E. However, now there is a solution. Thanks to a couple of QGIS developers, who kindly provided me the correct code for r.drain, i can use a vector file instead of the couple of coordinates (N,E). The new version of r.drain will be issued in QGIS2.14. the change in the current r.drain.txt file is ParameterVector instead of ParameterMultipleInput.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! You should post your comment as an **answer** and accept it (click the green-faded tick on the left-hand side of the answer when posted) to mark this question off =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@joseph, hope to have understood. Thanks for letting me know. The question is closed.